# How can I override Windows keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keyboard-shortcuts, d

I would like to create an application to manage the positions of windows on the Windows Desktop. I am using the [Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-functions) to accomplish this.

However, keyboard commands like `Windows` + `Arrow Keys`, `Windows` + `Alt` + `Arrow Keys`, etc. are already used by DWM. I want my program to respond to these macros and override the default functionality. How may I do so?

I was wondering how AutoHotKey does it, for example.

I should add that I am using the D language to write this application, but I can port any C++ code to D easily.

Edit: I found [this function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), would it override the system default?

Comment: As documented in the [API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx) you linked to: *"Keyboard shortcuts that involve the WINDOWS key are reserved for use by the operating system."*

Comment: @IInspectable So if you're telling me it's not possible how do other applications (namely AutoHotKey) do it?

Comment: I'm not telling you, that it's impossible. I'm just quoting the documentation to remind you, what the system expects from responsible developers. *"[H]ow do other applications (namely AutoHotKey) do it?"* - AutoHotkey is [open source](https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey). You can answer that question yourself.

Comment: IInspectable is right. This can cause problems and the documentation even warns you... tread really carefully!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the API function you are looking for is [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) with a [`LowLevelKeyboardProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx)

Since you tagged your question with the `d` tag, I'm assuming you may be using the D programming language.  You can find an example using the D programming language at https://github.com/JinShil/Dsus2/blob/b08c66c6a6efb46134c409aac9f1c600d62f99fa/Dsus2/main.d#L184  I am the author of that code.

Comment: `SetWindowsHookEx`*